# how to decompose time in different part in php?

Tags: php

I want to decompose a time in two part, I mean by that, I want to take the left side and the right side, like a cut off right ?

> 22:02:00
>
> 23:00:00
>
> 23:12:00

Imagine those number, it doesn't matter if there's seconds or not, so we can kick them

> 22:02
>
> 23:00
>
> 23:12

Now, I to take the separate hour and minute. How can we do that ?

Comment: [strptime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to just cut out the first 5 characters of the string:

```
$time = '22:02:00';
echo substr($time, 0, 5); // 22:02
```

You can also parse the time using e.g. the `DateTime` class:

```
$time = '22:02:00';
$parsed = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $time);
echo $parsed->format('H:i');
```

As Mark Baker commented, the [`strptime()` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) can also be used:

```
$time = '22:02:00';
$parsed = strptime($time, '%H:%M');
echo str_pad($parsed['tm_hour'], 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . ':' . str_pad($parsed['tm_min'], 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Regular expressions would also work:

```
$time = '22:02:00';
preg_match('/^(?P<hour>\d{2}):(?P<minute>\d{2})/', $time, $result);
if (count($result) > 0) {
    echo "{$result['hour']}:{$result['minute']}";
}
```